# Wireless disabled by hardware switch on hp pavilion 15-p214dx

Tags: networking, drivers, wireless, suspend, hp

Two days ago i installed **Ubuntu 16.04** alongside **Windows 8**, and started using it. I noticed wifi stops working once i resume working after suspend.
When i click the Wifi icon everything is greyed except Enable Networking. 
I tried almost all the solution from the internet. I tried **rfkill** also.
Using **rfkill list all** and **rfkill unblock all** but nothing worked.

I thought this is problem with **Ubuntu 16.04** so i installed the fresh **Ubuntu 15.04**. I have been using **Ubuntu 15.04** since 2 years on my other toshiba laptop and never faced any problem with it. But the problem is still the same on Hp laptop.

I tried updating realtek drivers, that did not work. I also tried `sudo systemctl restart network-manager.service`, even this did not work.

I first thought this might be because i installed **tlp** and **powertop** on **16.04** but now i don't have anything installed on **15.04** and the problem still exists.

And yes one thing i did while installing both ubuntu was i did not connect  it to wifi, as it asks for downloading its other 3rd party software and drivers.

My wireless card details:

```
*-network               
   description: Wireless interface
   product: RTL8188EE Wireless Network Adapter
   vendor: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
   physical id: 0
   bus info: pci@0000:08:00.0
   logical name: wlan0
   version: 01
   serial: ac:d1:b8:40:20:d7
   width: 64 bits
   clock: 33MHz
   capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list ethernet physical wireless
   configuration: broadcast=yes driver=rtl8188ee driverversion=3.19.0-15-generic firmware=N/A ip=192.168.43.5 latency=0 link=yes multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11bgn
   resources: irq:53 ioport:4000(size=256) memory:c3100000-c3103fff


 *-network
   description: Ethernet interface
   product: RTL8101E/RTL8102E PCI Express Fast Ethernet controller
   vendor: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
   physical id: 0
   bus info: pci@0000:09:00.0
   logical name: eth0
   version: 08
   serial: d0:bf:9c:90:d8:ab
   size: 10Mbit/s
   capacity: 100Mbit/s
   width: 64 bits
   clock: 33MHz
   capabilities: pm msi pciexpress msix vpd bus_master cap_list ethernet physical tp mii 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd autonegotiation
   configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=r8169 driverversion=2.3LK-NAPI duplex=half firmware=rtl8106e-2_0.0.1 04/23/13 latency=0 link=no multicast=yes port=MII speed=10Mbit/s
   resources: irq:48 ioport:3000(size=256) memory:c3004000-c3004fff memory:c3000000-c3003fff


nmcli general output:

STATE         CONNECTIVITY  WIFI-HW   WIFI      WWAN-HW  WWAN    
disconnected  none          disabled  disabled  enabled  enabled
```

Comment: One solution i found out is to use **hibernate** rather than using **suspend**.  I tried hibernating the system and after resuming the wifi was there.  Yes wifi is working after **hibernate** but not after **suspend**

Comment: - Its likely to be a bug that causes the *network manager* to stay asleep. Which would also explain why it does work after **hibernate**, which kinda shuts down and restarts the computer. -

Comment: Suspend the computer and run this `nmcli general`. Then edit your post with the output

Comment: @M.Becerra Edited post with output.

Comment: Guess I was wrong, as it doesn't say `asleep` in STATE.

Comment: Check this, and do it after suspend http://askubuntu.com/questions/425155/my-wireless-wifi-connection-does-not-work-what-information-is-needed-to-diagnos/425205#425205